# RegEx - How to find and replace words in a large text-file?

Tags: regex, backreference

I have a text file with data like:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY document_labels
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_g71qgs6l2ufr3170u44j5fpk3 FOREIGN KEY (label_id) REFERENCES application_value(id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY rule_group_functionality_mapping
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_g8twyunj9bm096sqywdi8rcx8 FOREIGN KEY (rule_group) REFERENCES application_value(id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY time_track
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_gmpyguqbpm1ndjjsxvt03wq4g FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_account(user_id);
```

I want to replace all the words that are like

```
fk_<some gibberish>
```

with

```
fk_<word between ONLY and nextline>_<word between REFERENCES and starting brace>
```

For example, change:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY document_labels
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_g71qgs6l2ufr3170u44j5fpk3 FOREIGN KEY (label_id)
REFERENCES application_value(id);
```

To:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY document_labels
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_document_labels_application_value FOREIGN KEY (label_id)
REFERENCES application_value(id);
```

So far, I can individually search the words I need but could not perform the replace.

To find fk_someGibberish in the text I am doing:

```
(?s)(?<=fk_)(.*?)(?= FOREIGN KEY)
```

To find word between ONLY and nextline I have:

```
(?s)(?<=ONLY )(.*?)(?=\n)
```

and to find word between REFERENCES and starting bracket I have:

```
(?s)(?<=REFERENCES)(.*?)(?=\()
```

All these have been tested at [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oH8uH3/1)

Comment: What tool/program are you using?

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong regex101 fiddle.

Comment: I tried it using regex101 online tool (link posted). But it doesn't really matter if it is online. I do have TextMate and Sublime Text on my Mac, if that helps. Thanks

Comment: @trincot I am not sure how to post the link to my actual change. Can you help?

Comment: you can match on RegEx101.com, but not replace, choose some programming language

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, check out the RegEx101.com "substitution" panel.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If you click  SUBSTITUTION at the bottom of the page you will see a window for substitution. Also, the tool doesn't matter. If you are aware of something better please let me know. I can try that.

Comment: thanks for *substitution* hint .. and good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex with capturing groups:

```
(\bONLY\h+)(.+)(\R.*?fk)_\S+(.+?\bREFERENCES\h+)([^(]+)
```

and replace using:

```
$1$2$3_$2_$5$4$5
```

**Explanation:**

```
(\bONLY\h+)          # match & capture ONLY followed by 1 or more horizontal spaces
(.+)                 # match & capture till end of line
(\R.*?fk)            # match & capture newline followed by any text upto fk
_\S+                 # match underscore followed by 1 or more non-whitespace chars
(.+?\bREFERENCES\h+) # match & capture any text followed by REFERENCES and 1+ spaces
([^(]+)              # match & capture upto next (
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ8gJ8/2)

Comment: Can you please also explain your answer a bit as I have very limited knowledge of RegEx?

Comment: Added explanation. I also suggest looking at the demo link for more clarity.

Comment: May I also ask how did you share the demo link? Whenever I share it it gives the default page.

Comment: @EMM: You must save your changes on `regex101` site and it will generate a new link for you. Once generate you can copy/paste that link here

Comment: Ok, one last question.. What is going on here -- $1$2$3_$2_$5$4$5?

Comment: These are back-references to various groups matched. Please check demo link for each value being captured.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your regex flavor:

```
^(?:ALTER\ TABLE\ ONLY\ )        # match ALTER TABLE ONLY
([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]                 # capture anything not a newline
(?:ADD\ CONSTRAINT\ )            # match ADD CONSTRAINT
fk_\S+(?=.*REFERENCES\ ([^()]+)) # match fk_, followed by not a whitespace
                                 # pos. lookahead capturing anything after REFERENCES
```

Replace this with:

```
ALTER TABLE $1\n
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_$1_$2
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iV3wS8/2).

Comment: Can you please also explain your answer a bit as I have very limited knowledge of RegEx?

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++:

```
Search: ALTER TABLE ONLY (\w+)(\s+)ADD CONSTRAINT fk_\w+(.*?)REFERENCES (\w+)
Replace: ALTER TABLE ONLY $1$2ADD CONSTRAINT fk_$1_$4$3REFERENCES $4
```

This matches the whole command, capturing the important bits, and reconstructs the command the way you want it using a blend of plain text and the captured bits.

Bracketing captures as a numbered group, and `$n` puts that numbered group back.